# Visio 2013 Preview and VB6: Microsoft Office cannot verify the license for this product

Tags: vb6, ms-office, visio, office-2013

I am trying to test our application against Visio 2013 but am having an issue which raises a message in Visio 2013 Preview "Microsoft Office cannot verify the license for this product. You should repair the office program by using Control Panel".

I have a simple VB6 form with a button on it. In the button event handler I have the following code.

```
Private Sub Command3_Click()
   Dim visoObj As Visio.Application

   Set visoObj = New Visio.Application

   visoObj.Visible = True
End Sub
```

On the click the Visio application opens but the message "Microsoft Office cannot verify the license for this product. You should repair the office program by using Control Panel" opens.

I have checked that the product is activated and tried uninstall/reinstall/repair/re enter key from add/remove programs.

I have also tried

```
cscript ospp.vbs /act
```

as described in http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_home-office_install/office-cannot-verify-the-license-for-this-product/3bb811ad-29d6-49c7-a3d0-4634c154d155?msgId=be64dcd6-ab02-4388-bb09-c9ab41ffe9ab

Has anybody got VB6 and Visio 2013 preview to work?

You also get this message if you try adding a Visio 2013 drawing control onto a VB6 form.

I have also successfully tried similar code to open Word 2013 Preview and Excel 2013 Preview. This has worked fine. Just can't figure out what is wrong with Visio.

Any Help?

Answer (score 2):

To fix this issue I had to turn off XP SP3 compatibility on the VB6.exe.
After turning this off I could create the Visio.Application dynamically without the license message.

But this just caused me to find another issue.

Visio 2013 Preview Drawing Control doesn't work in the IDE for VB6 or Visual Studio 2012 C# forms.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/f5c30d5d-4d53-4fd5-a14e-3ce22223c8c9